# How to npm i ssh2 without errors on Windows?

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio, cmake, ssh2

`npm i ssh2` ends with:

> MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function
> __except_handler4 [c:\xxxxxxx\git\sdk\v2\master\node_modules\yyyy\node_modules\cpu-features\build\cpufeatures.
> vcxproj]
> c:\xxxxxxx\git\sdk\v2\master\node_modules\yyyy\node_modules\cpu-features\build\Release\cpufeatures.node : fatal
> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [c:\SAPDevelop\git\sdk\v2\master\node_modules\irpa_core\node_modules\cpu-feature
> s\build\cpufeatures.vcxproj]

As you can see, the problem is in `cpu-features`. I was able to look at the `cpu-features` build files for MS Visual Studio (by running `npm i cpu-features`) and I *think* I found the root cause:
the node module (cpufeatures.node) is compiled with the `/MT` option (the C/C++ Run Time is to be statically linked)
But the DLL is linked to `cpu_features.lib`, witch is itself built with a link to `utils.lib`...
The two libraries, `cpu_features.lib` and `utils.lib` are compiled with the `/MD` switch (C/C++ Run Time is to be dynamicaly linked)

That's not correct. On Windows with Visual Studio, all libs linked to a DLL must use the same option with respect to link to the C/C++ Run Time. The DLL `cpufeatures.node` **build fine** after MANUALLY changing `/MD` to `/MT` in the Visual Studio projects for the two libraries.

I know nothing about `cmake`.

Question: how to successfully `npm install ssh2` *on Windows*?

(I created an issue here: https://github.com/mscdex/cpu-features/issues/3 with no avail so far. I understand that cpu-features is *optional* for ssh2. Alternative question: how to tell `npm install ssh2` to not try to build cpu-features?)

```
 Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bits 21H1 build 19043.1237
 node v14.17.6
 npm 6.14.15
 node-gyp 8.2.0
 cmake 3.21.3
 Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.11.3
```

Comment: The bug in the optional dependency `cpu_feature` is fixed on github (https://github.com/mscdex/cpu-features) but not on npmjs.com, per upstream choice, for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the alternative question:

```
npm install nan
npm install ssh2 --no-optional
```

Comment: For newer versions use `npm install ssh2 --omit=optional` instead